# Intercepting c++ exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

So my c++ program just crashed, and the error I got was:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted
```

Now, what I've added recently to my code is a SIGSEGV handler, so if it was a segmentation fault, it would proceed to print the stack trace.

How do I go about making an exit handler for uncaught (or more like uncatchable) exceptions in c++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [set_terminate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/) function which sets the terminate handler function:

> A terminate handler function is a
>   function automatically called when the
>   exception handling process has to be
>   abandoned for some reason. This
>   happens when a handler cannot be found
>   for a thrown exception, or for some
>   other exceptional circumstance that
>   makes impossible to continue the
>   handling process.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Will it be able to access the stack trace of wherever the exception came from? I guess I'll find out soon..

Comment: @kamziro: You'll probably be able to see the stack trace in the debugger, but I don't think there is a way to get it from the code.

Comment: Ah, it works, I was just reusing my SIGSEGV handler which uses backtrace and addr2line (linux) to convert things to a nicely formatted stack trace.

Comment: However, now I can't get the actual exception string (like 'std::length_error') since set_terminate's function doesn't take any arguments. Is there a way to grab this information as well?

Comment: @kamziro: It seems there is a gcc specific way to do this. See http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/03/21/catching-uncaught-exceptions-within-terminate/

Comment: Since the link given in the comment by @vitaut is broken, see my answer below for an option to get the exception inside the set_terminate function

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by @vitaut, if you are using C++11 you can check for and get the current exception within the handler specified by `std::set_terminate`.

[According to Daniel Krügler](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.std.c++/gThVi-yActI/HE_msGQckc8J) who refers to the standard quoted below, there is an implicit exception handler active during the call to `std::terminate`, which means that we can use `std::current_exception` to both check whether there is an active exception and also examine it.

The C++11 standard [working draft N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), section 15.3.7 (**emphasis** mine):

> A handler is considered active when initialization is complete for the formal parameter (if any) of the catch
>   clause. *[ Note: The stack will have been unwound at that point. — end note ]* **Also, an implicit handler
>   is considered active when std::terminate() or std::unexpected() is entered due to a throw**. A handler
>   is no longer considered active when the catch clause exits or when std::unexpected() exits after being
>   entered due to a throw.

---

[Stealing from Andrzej's C++ blog](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/), here is an example of how this can be done:

```
[[noreturn]] void onTerminate() noexcept
{
    if( auto exc = std::current_exception() ) { 
        // we have an exception
        try{
            rethrow_exception( exc ); // throw to recognize the type
        }
        catch( MyException const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
        catch( MyOtherException const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
        catch( std::exception const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
        catch( ... ) {
            // additional action
        }
    }

    std::_Exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `try`-`catch(...)` at the to level of your program. Something like this:

```
try {
   doStuff();
} catch( std::exception& e ) {
  //handle std::exception-derived exceptions
} catch(...) {
  //handle all other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own terminate handler with [`std::set_terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate).

You can catch all C++ exceptions with a catch-all clause `catch (...) {}`.